# lmer: Anova gives Warning message: In beta - betaH : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, statistics, warnings, lme4

I am performing a simple general linear mixed model, using `lmer`. I would like to find out if there are any differences in flower visitor abundance between nutrient treatment plots. 
I have 7 nutrient treatment plots, each replicated once in 3 blocks.
The treatments are: `control`, `N`, `P`, `K`, `NPK`, `f_control`, `f_NPK`.
The blocks are: `A`, `B`, `C`.

My data looks like this:

```
totvisobs<-plots$tot_vis_obs_withesc
Treatment<-plots$Treatment
Block<-plots$Block
Block<-as.factor(Block)
```

With:

```
Block: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
Treatment: Factor w/ 7 levels "control","f_control",..: 1 4 7 5 6 2 3 1 4 7 ...
totvisobs: int [1:21] 63 57 38 150 97 38 83 53 69 47 ...
```

My model:

```
totvisobs_glmm<-lmer(totvisobs~Treatment+(1|blocks), REML = TRUE, data = plots)
Anova(totvisobs_glmm, test.statistic = "F")
```

This is what I get:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)

Response: totbeeobs
              F Df Df.res   Pr(>F)   
Treatment 5.102  6     12 0.008054 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

> Warning message: In beta - betaH :   longer object length is not a
>   multiple of shorter object length

I don't know if I should ignore this warning or not. I have been trying everything to solve it but I don't know what to do since my data looks fine.
Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Thank you in advance!

Lisanne